# how to check in TPL whether a variable has been changed in other threads

Tags: c#, task-parallel-library

I need to check for a variable in a TPL program whether it has been changed. For example, if a thread changes a volatile string variable, other threads dont need to change it. As the type of variable is volatile other threads can use it. How can I do it?

Comment: I think in TPL is not that simple!

Answer (score 3):

1. `volatile` probably does not do what you think it does. Don't use it because it does not give you what you need.
2. You cannot find out if a variable has been change just like that. Maybe you can add a `bool wasChanged = false` and set it to true when the variable was written to. Remember to use proper synchronization for this (probably `lock`).

Comment: Could you explain a bit why volatile cant be used? I am using Parallel.foreach BTW

Comment: What do you think it does? Then I can say why doesn't do that :) Most of the time you just want to use locks, or for very simple operations Interlocked.

Comment: Here is the scenario: 1. I have a proxy that is shared among all the threads. 2. if this proxy gets blocked, then only ONE thread needs to dequeue a proxy from ProxyQueue, not all of them. for dequeuing I am using mutex right now so only one thread at a time can enter the function.

Comment: If you take a mutex then you are already synchronized through mutual exclusion. That sounds good. Not sure I understand the whole picture though. Probably you're better served with a new question rather than this small comment box.

Answer (score 2):

A sure-fire way to check a shared variable versus its expected value, given restrictions on the variable type, is using [Interlocked](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.interlocked.aspx) operations.